# Fields drop-down contain “$75” data in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I have created various forms. One of the forms I created contains a $75 pricing for orders. Now, somehow all of my other forms drop-down menu fields have this data inserted.

How can I rectify this problem?

Here is an example: https://www.cognitoforms.com/LawrenceTham1/F0101ExpatServices

And here is the form that should contain the $75 pricing: https://www.cognitoforms.com/LawrenceTham1/LampeBergerOrder